# DNS Mystery in Heroku CNAME Redirection

Tags: heroku, dns, host, cname

I have something quite mysteriously not working in my DNS configuration :

- My app is at : `http://my-domain.herokuapp.com`
- I configured `my-domain.com` the following way :

  ```
  @ 10800 IN A 174.129.25.170
  www 10800 IN CNAME my-domain.herokuapp.com.
  ```

using wwwizer.

So, `http://my-domain.com` redirects to `http://www.my-domain.com` which CNAMEs to `http://my-domain.herokuapp.com`

Everything seems fine, but when I enter `http://my-domain.com` or `http://www.my-domain.com`, I get : `Heroku | No such app` error message.

So I tried this :

```
host http://www.my-domain.com
www.my-domain.com is an alias for my-domain.herokuapp.com.
my-domain.herokuapp.com has address 54.243.92.108
```

and

```
host http://my-domain.herokuapp.com
my-domain.herokuapp.com has address 184.72.248.52
```

I can't see where the problem is. WWWizer seems working fine, but it feels like CNAME hasn't refreshed since the herokuapp IP changed ...

Any tip would be super appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you added all of the possible incoming domains to your application?

Comment: You mean on the Heroku side ? When I type `heroku domains`
I get :
`=== my-domain Domain Names` 
`my-domain.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @neil-middleton comment, I found the solution.

I did added earlier `heroku domains:add my-domain.com`

but did not for 
`heroku domains:add www.my-domain.com`

which is the one that matters here. (Though I left both in case)

So it seems heroku has its own internal DNS control when CNAME-ing *.herokuapp.com where it gets as an entry the `heroku domains`.

This is logical to avoid setting CNAME to an app one don't own.